# Method or function application on list of strings with if conditions

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement

I have two lists as follows:

```
a = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
b = ["aaa", "bbb", "ddd", "eee"]
```

I would like to have a `print` (a function or a method more in general) of the `a[i]` elements if `a[i]==b[j]`.
This is the code I wrote, it doesn't work because it returns four times the condition.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if a[i] == b[i]:
            print (a[i])
```

Comment: do you want to compare items at same index or all combinations and see which match. If the latter what about duplicates?

Comment: I want to take just the equal items once

Answer (score 1):

try the following code snippet:

```
a = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
b = ["aaa", "bbb", "ddd", "eee"]

output = [e for e in a if e in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is set intersection.

```
a = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
b = ["aaa", "bbb", "ddd", "eee"]

set(a).intersection(set(b))
```

The output is:

```
{'aaa', 'bbb'}
```

Comment: Thank you Roy, I was not aware of intersection method.

Comment: Do you mind accepting this as an answer for future generations?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you have the condition `a[i] == b[i]` which should be `a[i] == b[j]` this should solve the problem

Comment: provide some solution for duplicates though, as if only that is fixed, still there will be duplicates